# send json Array to struts2 action using Ajax post

Tags: jsp, jquery, arrays, struts2-jquery

In my struts2 application, I have requirement to send list of pojo to struts2 action. But unable to get the way to get that on action.

Here is my JavaScript function.

```js
function go() {
    var requests = Array();
    var url='testUrl';
      $('.innertable').each(function(index){
         var form= $(this).closest('form');
         if(index!=0)
             {
             var xVal=form.find("#xVal"+index).val();
             }
             else
              {
             var xVal=form.find("#xVal"+index).val();
              } 
         var testPojo = {
                 xVal:xVal
             }
         requests.push(testPojo);
         });
         alert('======='+JSON.stringify(requests));
                      $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: JSON.stringify(requests),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                       //success code
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                             window.location.reload();
                        }
         });

}
```

My struts2 action

```java
public String testUrl()
    {
        //here what code i can use to get List of pojo
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

When I run this I get request's value in alert:

```
[{"xVal":"$3,000"},{"xVal":"$5,000"}]
```

How can I get this value in struts2 action?

Comment: can you print your output as i have problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062180/sending-array-from-jquery-to-servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue.I am sharing here which might be useful for any one else.

In place of sending data using ajax Here i am sending data appending in query string of url.Here is sample.

```
                       $.ajax({
                        url: url+"?data="+JSON.stringify(requests),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                        //success code
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                            alert('there is some problem in updating data');

                        }
         });
```

This is the code of action

```
    public String testUrl()
    {

        String data = request.getParameter("data");

        System.out.println("data is :"+data);
        List<TestPojo> testPojos=new ArrayList<TestPojo>();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);

                TestPojo testPojo = new TestPojo();

                testPojo.setTestField(jsonObject.get("testField").toString());

                testPojos.add(testPojo);    
            }
           //additional code here 

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ravi Kant First why you are sending json string to action? I mean why json format? Any specific reasons? You need to receive this requests variable by declaring requests as String variable in Action file and use getter and setter method for get the value from form.

```
private String requests;

public String getRequests() {
    return requests;
}

public void SetRequests(String requests) {
    this.requests = requests;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply vinoth.I already tried this using getter and setter but it's not working for me and getting null.That's why i tried to use JSON format.

Comment: Hey thats great, Use javascript array to send the values to action like `var requests = []; requests.push(xVal);` and get this value as String array in java. Try this and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

For example : you can try this way

```
 $.ajax({

        type : 'post',      

        url : 'getsampleZone.action',

        data: "disctric ="+ value,

        dataType: 'json',    

        async: true ,

        success:function(x){

            alert("aasdsds");       

        }                       

});
```

In Action Page ;

```
    private String disctric;

    System.out.println("disctric >>>>"+getDisctric());

    public String getDisctric() {

    return disctric;

    }

public void setDisctric(String disctric) {
    this.disctric = disctric;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```js
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(requests);    
                      $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: "jsonAct="+jsonStr ,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                       //success code
                        }
```

and then generate setter getter for jsonAct in action class

```
private String jsonAct;




public String getJsonAct() {
    return jsonAct;
}

public void setJsonAct(String jsonAct) {
    this.jsonAct = jsonAct;
}
```

I daced the same issue and it got resolved.